# Проблема с .csv в D3.js

Tags: javascript, массивы, csv, d3.js

Начал изучать d3.js, и столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу правильно распарсить .csv файл. Есть data.csv c данными типа:

```
city,human
Москва,90
Адлер,88
Питер,158
```

И есть сам js файл:

```
var dataCSV = d3.csv('data.csv', function(d) {
                return {
                  city : d.city ,
                  human: +d.human
                };
              }, function(error, rows) {
                  console.log(rows);
                });

d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('p')
    .data(dataCSV)
    .enter()
    .append('p')
    .text(function(d) {return dataCSV.human});
```

В браузере, по идее, должны появиться элементы 'p' в количестве строк в .csv файле, и содержанием human каждой строки. Но увы и ах, этого не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataCSV = d3.csv('data.csv', function(d) {
                  return {
                    city : d.city ,
                    human: +d.human
                  };
                }, function(error, rows) {
                    d3.select("body").select("p#own")
                        .data(rows)
                        .enter().append("p").attr("id", "own")
                        .text("test");
                  });
```

Во-первых, данные из .csv получаются позже, чем вы пытаетесь прикрепить абзацы. Во-вторых select и selectAll работают по-разному. Приведённый выше кусок сделан с select, если нужен именно selectAll, замените на это:

```
d3.selectAll("p#own")
                        .data(rows)
                        .enter().append("p").attr("id", "own")
                        .text("Test");
```